# std::unique_lock не захватывает мьютекс

Tags: c++, многопоточность, stl

Разрабатываю имплементацию очереди задач. 
В классе содержатся следующие данные:

```
class TaskQueue
{
private:
    std::queue<BasicTaskPtr> m_queue;
    std::condition_variable  m_cv;
    std::mutex               m_mutex;

public:

    explicit TaskQueue()
        : m_queue()
        , m_cv()
        , m_mutex()
    {}

    BasicTaskPtr popTask();
    void pushTask(BasicTaskPtr task);
};
```

Реализации методов:

```
BasicTaskPtr TaskQueue::popTask()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

    std::cout << "locked" << std::endl;

    // condition_variable может выдать ложное срабатывание,
    // поэтому устанавливаем предикат окончания ожидание 
    m_cv.wait(lock, [&]()
        {
            return !this->m_queue.empty();
        });

    auto task = m_queue.front();
    m_queue.pop();

    std::cout << "unlocked" << std::endl;

    return task;
}

void TaskQueue::pushTask(BasicTaskPtr task)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

    if (m_queue.size() <= Constants::kMaxTaskQueueSize)
    {
        m_queue.push(task);
        m_cv.notify_one();
    }
}
```

Поток исполнитель выглядит следующим образом:

```
void Executor(TaskQueue& queue)
{
    while (true)
    {
        queue.popTask()->execute();
    }
}
```

Поток генератор выглядит следующим образом:
class TestTask : public BasicTask
{
public:

```
TestTask(const std::string &str)
    : BasicTask(BasicTask::Json({ {"str", "qwerty_" + str} }))
{}

void execute() override
{
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " - " << m_input["str"].get<std::string>() << std::endl;
}
```

};

```
void Producer(TaskQueue &queue)
{
    int i{ 0 };
    while (i++ < 60)
    {
        queue.pushTask(std::make_shared<TestTask>(TestTask(std::to_string(i))));
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

Создаю все вот так:

```
TaskQueue queue;

std::thread executor_thread_1(Executor, std::ref(queue));
std::thread executor_thread_2(Executor, std::ref(queue));
std::thread producer_thread(Producer, std::ref(queue));

producer_thread.join();
```

На что получаю следующий вывод:
    lockedlocked
То есть получается, что мьютекс пропускает второй поток при том, что первый его все еще не разблокировал. Не понимаю что сделал не так

Comment: Так вы же сами сказали: `std::try_to_lock`. Разумеется будет "мьютекс пропускает второй поток при том, что первый его все еще не разблокировал". Для этого `std::try_to_lock` и предназначен. Зачем вы передаете `std::try_to_lock`, если вы не хотите "пропускания потока"?

Comment: изменил на auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_mutex);. Если верить cppreference, в таком варианте мьютекс будет захвачен. Однако поведение не изменилось

Comment: Да, но `m_cv.wait(lock,` будет *разблокировать* `lock` на входе в ожидание и блокировать его снова на выходе из ожидания. Как только `m_cv.wait` разблокировал `lock`, второй поток может идти вперед. Поэтому и получается "locked locked".